# Need a strategy for an efficient autocomplete in Rails across multiple attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, autocomplete

I have a form for submitting an order, and I need an autocomplete field that searches across three attributes in the associated customer model: first name, last name, and customer_number (as opposed to customer.id). I know about the `rails3-jquery-autocomplete` gem found here http://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete, and got it working well, but a question has occurred to me -- is there a more efficient way to make the autocomplete work without having to query the db every time?

The other solution that occurred to me is to create a new indexed attribute in the customer model -- call it autocomplete_data. Whenever a new customer is added via the usual new customer form, an `:after_create` callback could populate the field. Would this speed up the performance? Or am I overthinking it?

**UPDATE**

I'm embarassed to say that I just didn't search hard enough the first time around -- I think this actually answers my question:
[Rails: Efficiently searching by both firstname and surname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147492/rails-efficiently-searching-by-both-firstname-and-surname)